# React - Click button and delete a list element

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In one of my components, I create a list with list items using  .map() function.
Here's a code:

```
tasksFiltered.map((task, keyID) => {
return (<li key={task.id} className={'todo-list__list-item'}>
    <span>{task.text}</span> 
    <button key={task.id} onClick={this.props.deleteTask}><FaTrashAlt /></button>
</li>)
```

What I'm struggle with is I want to add deleteTask function to each button.
After clicking in this button I should check if this button is in this specific LI element (if is connected to this li's key). If the answer is yes, I should setState and change isCompleated from false to true.

So I don't know how to check whether this button bellows to this li element or not.
Second thing is that I wonder how I can change a state when it looks like that:

```
  state = {
    imputValue: 'Type new item',
    inputText: '',
    tasks: []
  }
```

and after submitting the form, the created array's element looks like that:

```
   {
      id: (Math.random() + Math.random()),
      text: this.state.inputText,
      isDeleted: false,
    }
```

How can I change just that one property of this specific array's item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the function at `this.props.deleteTask` needs a reference to the specific `task.id` value, simply pass that value to that function.  Something like this:

```
onClick={() => this.props.deleteTask(task.id)}
```

This assumes that the `deleteTask` function accepts that ID value as a parameter (which it should).  Something like:

```
function deleteTask(id) {
  //...
}
```

The main thing to note is the syntax in the `onClick`.  Rather than passing it a function reference, we're passing it a new anonymous function which has just one line that calls another function, but passes any custom arguments you like to that function.  (When we pass only a function reference, that function would be called by the framework and receive the click event argument instead.)

---

For your second question, that sounds like an entirely different question and may be worth creating a new Stack Overflow question specifically for that.  I recommend clarifying in that question how you currently update the state and indicate specifically what isn't working in that approach.